# How can i use JUCE library in cinder?

Tags: c++, ide, installation, cinder, juce

I am familiar with cinder but I've never added a third party c++ library to a cinder project.  I need to use the midi parsing power of the JUCE api but don't know how to proceed in installing the library and then including it in my build.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm running osx 10.8.4 and xcode 4.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I'm not familiar with Cinder, I am quite familiar with JUCE. From what I gathered about Cinder, it's being a very basic cross-platform application framework, mores a platform, for doing really cool graphics stuff, but not nearly as general purpose as JUCE is. JUCE does not have to be the main() for your application. You can pull JUCE modules into your project on an as-needed basis. Read about JUCE's modular architecture here: http://www.juce.com/features.